# Resend email every 24 hour for 3 days

Tags: php, mysql, cron

After user registered on my website, we send him a confirmation email.
What i want is - to resend email for user, every 24 hours for 3 days.
So for example:

```
user_table
id , name, date_registered, is_active
```

If user just registered `is_active` is set to `0`

I want to create cronscript for example( i will run it every 15 minutes or so):

```
SELECT * FROM user_table 
where date_registered = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

And i can send email here, But the problem is next, after i sent him 1st email, i need somehow to check it after 48 hours `if is_active == 0` send email again, etc.

So the question is: how to determine that email has been set onece or twitce, etc..

Comment: You could create a new table and store all the emails you send out and at what time.  Then you could easily check this table

Comment: Add a column to a table containing the number of email's (of type) that have been sent?

Comment: Why dopn't you simply add a test for is_active into your SQL query to determine who gets an email

Comment: thanks, i am thinking of creating new table, because my `user` table is really big, and has alot of columns

Comment: Maybe a flag with the number of current sends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a column to store the date of last sent email, then you shoud be able to only send 3 emails.